# "string_name = string_name[3..-1]" what could the following line of ruby code mean?

Tags: ruby, string, syntax

I'm looking at some external code and saw a line of Ruby code that looks like this

```
string_name = string_name[3..-1]
```

what does the `[n..-x]` do or mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby supports negative indexing of arrays. So index -1 is the last element of the array, -2 is the second to last, etc. Think of starting at the beginning of the array, and wrapping around from the back.

So in this case, `string_names[3..-1]` is basically a substring from 3 to the end of the string.